# Regex comma delimited string validation

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that should be valid only if it has 2 characters and it is delimited by commas.

```
AD,AC,AN,JP (valid)
AD (valid) if user enter only one it must be validate
```

Must return invalid if it's a number or any other character besides comma or its length is greater than 2.

```
AD,12,AN,JP (invalid)
AAD,12,AN,JP (invalid)
AA,CC,ANA,JP (invalid)
AA,#C,AA,JP (invalid)
```

Comment: Haven't you tried anything before asking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This assumes that the input is always uppercase:

```
var reggie = new Regex(@"^[A-Z]{2}(,[A-Z]{2})*$");
```

If, on top of validating the input, you want to extract the data, you can then perform a simple split on the comma (regex split is not necessary):

```
if (reggie.IsMatch(inputString))
    string[] values = string.Split(',');
```

Comment: That's why they call you quick :) (Well OK, it took you 9 minutes, but it took me 14 seconds longer...)

Comment: You were pretty quick yourself. :)

Comment: what if i want to validate only upper case